# Showing google Recaptcha V3 floater only on specific Pages of React Application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

i've react application with multiple # routes & google recaptcha v3,

i want to show recaptcha floater only on specific pages (# route) like login & forms.

How to achieve this.

Tried -

```css
.grecaptcha-badge { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
#root #mainContainer .login:not(.empty) +  div>.grecaptcha-badge { 
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.grecaptcha-badge { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
#root #mainContainer .login ~ div>.grecaptcha-badge { 
    visibility: visible;
}
```

showing hiding by javascript > componentWillMount - >  page's componentwillmount calls before the google recaptcha renders, so it dont get the element

Comment: Using CSS as a means to hide recaptcha elements is a violation of the Google terms of service (https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en) unless you inform your users that you are using recaptcha by other means. If your goal is to simply omit recaptcha from certain pages, then I would recommend not rendering them at all (on those specific pages).

Comment: @Matt ok how? post code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this outside your component:

```js
const toggleCaptchaBadge = (show: boolean) => {
  const badge = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge')[0];
  if (badge && badge instanceof HTMLElement) {
    badge.style.visibility = show ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  }
};
```

Inside call this `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    toggleCaptchaBadge(true);
    return () => toggleCaptchaBadge(false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: this worked, but somewhere i read, its illegal to hide recaptcha, but this works

Comment: Check my reply. It should be the real solution because you dont need to use css styling to hide captcha, you can just conditionally choose to not render the component at all

Answer (score 4):

i (as many others) had the same issue.

in my case i use react-route where i can listen to path changes.
so i ended up removing the script and the badge element on pages i dont need it and adding it (if necessary) on certain paths.

```
const loadRecaptcha = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=lalala";
    script.id = 'recaptcha-script';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.append(script);
}

const removeRecaptcha = () => {
    const script = document.getElementById('recaptcha-script');
    if (script) {
        script.remove();
    }

    const recaptchaElems = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge');
    if (recaptchaElems.length) {
        recaptchaElems[0].remove();
    }
}
```

hope it helps in the future to someone

Comment: Thats ridiculous. that's not even a solution more like a "hack" as workaround. How does the library not support on which pages we can display captcha? I dont want to show it on ALL pages. only /contact for example

Comment: a workaround? maybe. But this is not ridiculous and nothing hacky in it

Comment: i figured out an actual solution where you don't have to use css styling to hide it. You can conditionally Not render google captcha at all. check my answer

Answer (score 1):

### I found a solution without having to use css styling, this way the google captcha does not get rendered at all if it's not supposed to be used.

1. Declare this in your root file of nextjs app:

```js
const router = useRouter();
const [
  showRecaptcha,
  setShowRecaptcha,
] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setShowRecaptcha((router.pathname === '/contact'));
}, [router.pathname]);
```

2. Then simply use conditional rendering for the `<Component {...pageProps} />`:

```js
{showRecaptcha ? <GoogleReCaptchaProvider
  reCaptchaKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY}
  scriptProps={{
    async: false,
    defer: true,
    appendTo: "body",
    nonce: undefined,
  }}
  container={{
    parameters: {
      theme: "dark",
    }
  }}
>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
:
  <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

This means the google captcha will render and work **only** once you navigate to the `/contact` route for example. You can put whatever or however many routes you want here.

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking to remove the Google's reCAPTCHA conditionally within your react app. We can use the CDM() life cycle method to:

1. Remove the script
2. Remove the reCAPTCHA badge

I was using [react-google-recaptcha-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha-v3), and checking the class of the GoogleReCaptchaProvider, we can find the **scriptId**
And as mentioned by Ivan Yulin above, it is exactly same.

```
const script = document.querySelector(scriptId);
        if (script) {
            script.remove();
        }
        const recaptchaElems = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge');
        if (recaptchaElems.length) {
            recaptchaElems[0].remove();
        }
```

But, even after removing the script I see in DOM the script

```
<script id="google-recaptcha-v3" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=*********"></script>
```

How can we remove this as well?